# Silverlight, open xml from outside application package

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have to open and read an xml file in my Silverlight application. I can't put this file in resources (my teacher's will). I tried to use this code:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("products.xml");
```

but got an error:

```
Cannot find file 'products.xml' in the application xap package.
```

This xml file is currently located in Debug folder next to .xap

What should I do to make it work?

XML file(just in case):

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>nameA</name>
    <desc>descA</desc>
    <image>imgA</image>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>nameB</name>
    <desc>descB</desc>
    <image>imgb</image>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>nameC</name>
    <desc>descC</desc>
    <image>imgC</image>
  </product>
</products>
```

Error caught in `returnResult(args.Result);` of Anthony's code:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details. ---> System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
   in System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
   in System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   in System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadAsync(Uri address, Object userToken)
   --- The end of stack trace of inner exceptions (my translation) ---
   in System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   in System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   in ProjektAI.MainPage.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetStreamFromUri>b__0(Object s, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs args)
```

Comment: if this is homework, you should have the #homework tag on it

Comment: Normal Silverlight only support reading files in the isolated storage or by using OpenFileDialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need the help of `WebClient` to download the xml file from the web server first.  Here is a utility method to help.

```
 public static void GetStreamFromUri(Uri uri, Action<Stream> returnResult)
 {
      WebClient client = new WebClient();
      client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, args) =>
      {
           returnResult(args.Result);
      };
      client.OpenReadAsync(uri);
 }
```

Your code would then use:-

```
GetStreamFromUri(new Uri("products.xml", UriKind.Relative), stream =>
{
     using (stream)
     {
         XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);

         // Rest of reader processing code called here.
     }
});

//  Note really really well: **Code here will run before XmlReader processing**
```

Likely the code you've written so far works synchronously.  Silverlight allows resources found in the XAP to be loaded and processed synchronously.  However network operations are always asynchronous.  Its my guess that "(my teacher's will)" is in fact that you learn this important asynchronous aspect of Silverlight coding and what effect it has on the way you need to code.

Comment: There are 3 minor mistakes in your code. I've corrected them and tried  to run your code (no further modifications). Unfortunately there is an exception in returnResult(args.Result): "An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details." I put my xml file in the question just in case.

Comment: @gisek:  I've spotted two related to OpenReadCompleted but I can't see a third?   What is the inner exception?  Place a `try..catch` in the OpenReadCompleted and do something silly in the catch like MessageBox.Show(err.ToString()), gives you somewhere to put a break point.  You are using a WebServer host?  The "products.xml" should end up in the ClientBin folder in the web project alongside the Xap, is that happening?

Comment: third mistake: GetStreamFromUri(Uri url <-- URL and than you use: OpenReadAsync(uri <-- URI;

The error added to the question.

Comment: I'm not using WebServer host. I saw there you have to choose between different options of ASP, while I'm supposed only to put silverlight object on my php website. It's possible though that I have a bad understanding here.

Comment: @gisek: So have if I've got this straight you are only allowed to put the silverlight XAP in the php website but the products.xml is outside the XAP?  So if its not in the XAP and its not on the website where else can it be?

Comment: I must put the .xap as a silverlight object in a php website (can't use ASP - I have to use Apache on Debian). The .xml can't be inside xap. And that's it - no more requirements. I just need to make it work. :)

Comment: @gisek: then put the .xml in the same folder you put the xap.

Comment: It's strange.. When I run it form visual studio or simply from debug folder id breaks. When I put it on Apache it magically works. Can you explain to me why?

Comment: @giseK:  Probably because you aren't using a web app host in your Visual studio solution.  VS will run the silverlight app in a standalone html file that is not served by a web server as result there is not server available to deliver your XML file.